# Number Betting Game

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I was sorting out some of my old code to look for troubleshooting exercises when I remembered my 'self taught' coding problems, and brought this out. The issue here is that it seems that if I do not get the predicted number accurately on the dot, it seems the re-set itself every time, which sorts of puzzles me as to why it happens.

```
import random

print('Welcome to the Number Guessing Game!')
print('The rules of the game are simple. If betting is chosen, please enter your bets.')

name1 = input('Please enter name of Player 1: ')
name2 = input('Please enter name of Player 2: ')

bet = input('Would you like to bet? Please answer with a "Yes" or "No": ')
betpool = 0
if bet == 'Yes':
    bettingamt = float(input('What would your bet be? Please input the number that everyone will equally contribute to, in integer form: '))
    if bettingamt > 0:
        betpool += bettingamt*2
        print('The betpool is now currently ${:.2f}'.format(betpool))
    else:
        print('You have not decided to bet, and will not be able to bet until the answer is achieved.')
elif bet == 'No':
    print('You have not decided to bet, and will not be able to bet until the answer is achieved.')

tries = 0

while True:
    (correctnum) = int(random.randint(1, 100))
    tries += 1

    (num1) = int(input('Try {}: Enter a number between 1 and 100 for Player 1 (or -1 to end, -2 to end and give up): '.format(tries)))
    (num2) = int(input('Try {}: Enter a number between 1 and 100 for Player 2 (or -1 to end, -2 to end and give up): '.format(tries)))

    if num1 == -1:
        print('{} has forfeited. {} wins by default! The betpool of {} is now {}!'.format(name1, name2, name1, name1))
        break
    if num2 == -1:
        print('{} has forfeited. {} wins by default! The betpool of {} is now {}!'.format(name2, name1, name2, name2))
        break

    if num1 == correctnum:
        print()
        print('Congratulations {}! You have won the betpool of {}!'.format(name1, betpool))
        print()
        print('Do come again! Bye-Bye!')
        print('Better luck next time, {}.'.format(name2))
        break
    elif num2 == correctnum:
        print()
        print('Congratulations {}! You have won the betpool of {}!'.format(name2, betpool))
        print()
        print('Do come again! Bye-Bye!')
        print('Better luck next time, {}.'.format(name1))
        break

    if num1 != correctnum:
        if num1 > correctnum:
            print('{} is too high'.format(num1))
        elif num1 < correctnum:
            print('{} is too low'.format(num1))
    if num2 != correctnum:
        if num2 > correctnum:
            print('{} is too high'.format(num2))
        elif num2 < correctnum:
            print('{} is too low'.format(num2))

    if tries == 5:
        print('Unlucky run, you got it wrong. The correct answer was {}'.format(correctnum))
        print()
        retry = input('Would you like to retry? If yes, your old bets will be added to the pot and you are now required to re-bet the same amount as the previous times. (Yes/No) ')
        if retry == 'Yes':
            print('You have chosen to retry. Your old bets will now be added onto the pot.')
            print('You have decided to play again.')
            print('Your bet has been renewed to the betpool.')
            print()
            betpool += betpool 
            print('The new betpool is now ${}.'.format(betpool))
            tries -= 5
            print('Your number of tries is now {}'.format(tries))

            continue
        else:
            print('You have decided to give up, and thus your betpool shall now be nulled. Thank you for playing, we do hope to see you again.')
            break
```

The output would look like this, which doesn't make sense to me, since it should either be 33 or 34.

```
Try 2: Enter a number between 1 and 100 for Player 1 (or -1 to end, -2 to end and give up): 34
Try 2: Enter a number between 1 and 100 for Player 2 (or -1 to end, -2 to end and give up): 34
34 is too high
34 is too high
Try 3: Enter a number between 1 and 100 for Player 1 (or -1 to end, -2 to end and give up): 33
Try 3: Enter a number between 1 and 100 for Player 2 (or -1 to end, -2 to end and give up): 33
33 is too low
33 is too low
```

I've tried various methods such as the arrangement of the `(correctnum) = int(random.randint(1, 100))` line in multiple places through the while loop but I still get no progress. I'm just rather puzzled with this issue.

Another example of the output error I face is:

```
Try 1: Enter a number between 1 and 100 for Player 1 (or -1 to end, -2 to end and give up): 34
Try 1: Enter a number between 1 and 100 for Player 2 (or -1 to end, -2 to end and give up): 65
34 is too low
65 is too low
Try 2: Enter a number between 1 and 100 for Player 1 (or -1 to end, -2 to end and give up): 74
Try 2: Enter a number between 1 and 100 for Player 2 (or -1 to end, -2 to end and give up): 88
74 is too high
88 is too high
Try 3: Enter a number between 1 and 100 for Player 1 (or -1 to end, -2 to end and give up): 72
Try 3: Enter a number between 1 and 100 for Player 2 (or -1 to end, -2 to end and give up): 69
72 is too high
69 is too high
Try 4: Enter a number between 1 and 100 for Player 1 (or -1 to end, -2 to end and give up): 72
Try 4: Enter a number between 1 and 100 for Player 2 (or -1 to end, -2 to end and give up): 69
72 is too high
69 is too high
Try 5: Enter a number between 1 and 100 for Player 1 (or -1 to end, -2 to end and give up): 72
Try 5: Enter a number between 1 and 100 for Player 2 (or -1 to end, -2 to end and give up): 69
72 is too high
69 is too high
Unlucky run, you got it wrong. The correct answer was 3
```

At one point (try 1 and 2), one could infer that the answer is 65<x<74, yet the final answer would be 3. This leads me into thinking that it resets each turn.

### Edit

Essentially, I know the issue lies in where I left my `(correctnum) = int(random.randint(1, 100))`, but how should I be generating it then?

Comment: I'm not seeing this error ([code](https://replit.com/@depperm/VastMajorPhases#main.py). Are you sure this is the code that has this problem?

Comment: What exactly are you saying the issue is? It seems to work accordingly. What are you saying is resetting?

Comment: The bet shouldn't be either 33 or 34, you you randomizer up to 1-100. Sorry if this sounds too harsh.

Comment: @depperm @mr_mooo_cow

Hey there, thanks for reaching back. I've edited my post based on your feedback, and I hope it is more accurate now. In either case, the issue is that during testing, when I assert that the correct number is in a certain range, in the next try, the correct number changes itself, as seen in the second output where on try 2, the answer is <34 yet on try 3, the answer is >33. I know my issue is mainly the placement of my ```(correctnum) = int(random.randint(1, 100))```, but where should I be placing that line in that case?

Comment: @NOTAGIF , heyo, could you explain further?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] with minimal code. Almost all of the code here is irrelevant to the problem. I was able to reproduce the same issue in just 11 lines by having only one player, no betting, no forfeiting, and no names. I could just give you the solution, but I think you'll learn a lot more by working it through yourself.

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment. The code seems to work correctly. Have you run this exact code?

Comment: @peng I understand now! I hope my answer works!

Comment: Formatting (Markdown) tip: for `inline formatting` you only need single backticks. Triples work but they are unnecessary. It's easier to edit posts where single backticks have been used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, so this is the problem.

You put the `(correctnum) = int(random.randint(1, 100))` INSIDE thie `while loop` when it tells you whether your guess is lower or higher than the `(correctnum)` that the program set. But then when it asks you again, it already chose a NEW number as the correct number. That's why things are so confusing. As for the answer, just put the `(correctnum) = int(random.randint(1, 100))` right above the while loop it's in right now.

Comment: Hmm, I get what you mean, but how about if I would like to 'retry' the game? It would maintain the same number :/

Comment: Ah, i understand. Then just duplicate the same code at the code where you retry. Like right before the continue.

Comment: Did that, didn't work